# Run python files and change strings with 1 file

Tags: python, python-3.x

lets say i have a folder which contains the following files:

> f1.py
>
> f2.py
>
> f3.py

in f1.py i got this code:

```
#O = "Random string"
print("ABCD")
#P = "Random string"
```

but in f2.py and f3.py i have this code:

```
#M = "Random string"
print("EFGH")
#Z = "Random string"
```

And i want to change the strings in the 'print' function in f2.py and f3.py to the string i have in print in f1.py, and run all the files in the folder after changing the strings, using f1.py

Comment: To clarify: you want to edit the _text files_ named "f2.py" and "f3.py", and then you want to execute all three files as python scripts. Is that right? Is it also a requirement that both of these actions be performed _by executing_ "f1.py" _as a python script?_ It seems like you're trying to do something very strange and we could use some more context.

Comment: Correct with running f1.py i want it to change the strings in other files in the folder and execute them. is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have more context why you want to do this.

This is possible, but in 99% of the cases it's not a god idea to write self modifying code, though it can be a lot of fun.

In fact you do not really write self modifying code, but more one piece of code modifying other files. But this is also rarely to be recommended.

What's more usual is, that one script analyzes / parses f1.py, extracts the data  writes some data into a file (e.g. a json file)
and f2.py and f3.py read the data from that file and do then print this data.

Is there a particular reason you want to have code, that is modifying other python files.

If you really want to have f2.py and f3.py modified, then there is another solution, which is called templating (you can for example use Jinji).
In this case you have two template files f2.py.template and f3.py.template.

you write a file parsing f1.py, extracting the data and creates f2.py from f2.py.template and the extracted data. (Same for f3.py.template and f3.py)

If you're really 100% sure, that you really want what you ask for.

Yes it is possible:

you write a script, tht opens and reads f1.py line by line, looks for the line `"#O = ",` then memorizes the next line.

Then it reads f2.py line by line and writes it to another file (e.g. next_version_of_f2.py). it reads in a line and writes it out until it encounters the line `#M = "Random string` in f2.py In this case the line will be written out, the desired print will be written out, the print line from f2.py will be read and ignored and then you read and write all the other lines.

Then you close `f2.py` and `next_version_of_f2.py`, rename f2.py into `f2.py.old` and rename `next_version_of_f2.py` to `f2.py`

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible but probably inadvisable.

Editing code should typically be a separate action from executing it (even when we use a single tool that can do both, like a lot of modern IDEs).

- It suggests a poor workflow. If you want f2.py to `print("ABCD")`, then it should be written that way.
- It's confusing. In order to understand what f2.py does, you have to mentally model the entirety of f1.py and f2.py, *and there's no indication of this in f2.py*.
- **It invites all kinds of difficult-to-debug situations.** What happens if f1.py is run twice at the same time? What if two *different versions* of f1.py are run at the same time? Or if I happen to be reading f2.py when you run f1.py? Or if I'm *editing* f2.py and *save my changes* while you're running f1.py?
- It's a security problem. For f1.py to edit f2.py, the user (shell, web-server, or other surface) calling f1.py has to have edit permissions on f2.py. That means that if they can get f1.py to do something besides what you intended (specifically, if they can get their own text in place of `"ABCD"`), then they can get arbitrary code execution *in everyone else's runtime!*

Note that it's perfectly fine to have code that generates or edits other code. The problem is when a *program* (possibly spanning multiple files) edits its own *source*.

[gelonida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309122/10135377) discusses some options, which are fine and appropriate for certain contexts such as managing user-specific configuration or building documents. That said, if you're familiar with functions, variables, imports, and other basics of computer science, then you may not even need a config.json file or a template engine.

**Reconsider the end result you're trying to accomplish.** Do some more research/reading, and if you're still stuck start a new question about the bigger-picture task.

Answer (score 0):

complaints about *XYZ* problems are old hat, so here's how to do what you want, even though it's awful and you really shouldn't.

#### f1.py

```py
import os
import re
import sys

#O = "Random string"
print("ABCD")
#P = "Random string"

selector = re.compile(
    r'#([A-Z]) = \"Random string\"\nprint\(\"([A-Z]{4})\"\)\n#([A-Z]) = \"Random string\"')
template = '''#{} = "Random string"
print("{}")
#{} = "Random string"'''

own_file_name = os.path.abspath(__file__)
own_directory = os.path.dirname(own_file_name)

def read_file(name: str) -> str:
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

find_replacement = selector.match(read_file(own_file_name))
replacement = find_replacement.group(1) if find_replacement else False
if not replacement:
    sys.exit(-1)

def make_replacement(reg_match) -> str:
    return template.format(reg_match.group(1), replacement, reg_match.group(3))

for dir_entry in os.listdir(own_directory):
    if dir_entry.is_file():
        original = read_file(dir_entry.path)
        with open(dir_entry.path, 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(selector.sub(make_replacement, original))

# this will cause an infinite loop, but you technically asked for it :)
for dir_entry in os.listdir(own_directory):
    if dir_entry.is_file():
        exec(read_file(dir_entry.path))
```

I want to be clear that the above is a joke. I haven't tested it, and I desperately hope it won't actually solve any problems for you.